# Angular2 not getting value if using Jquery Datepicker

Tags: javascript, jquery, angular2-template, angular2-forms

I am trying to use datepicker as:

```
<div class="form-group row">
                        <label class="col-md-3 col-form-label" for="l0">Date</label>
                        <div class="col-md-9">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control datepicker-only-init" formControlName="last_updated" placeholder="Select Date" />
                        </div>
                    </div>
```

in ts:

```
$(function(){
        $('.datepicker-only-init').datetimepicker({
            widgetPositioning: {
            horizontal: 'left'
            },
            icons: {
            time: "fa fa-clock-o",
            date: "fa fa-calendar",
            up: "fa fa-arrow-up",
            down: "fa fa-arrow-down",
            previous: 'fa fa-arrow-left',
            next: 'fa fa-arrow-right'
            },
            format: 'LL'
        });
    })
```

** My Datepicker displays well but I am unable to get its value again.

I am getting it as ;

```
this.testForm.controls['last_updated'].value;
```

Comment: can you please let me know your text box is in ng-repeat or not?

Comment: no its not in ng-repeat, also I have updated question.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution this:

```
<input type="text" class="form-control datepicker" id="datePicker" #datePicker formControlName="last_updated" placeholder="Select Date" (blur)="onDateChange(datePicker.value);"/>
```